# TESTNG, how to validates test case results to pass fail status

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-automation-framework, testng

Need help, my question here is how can I code it such when the result is not expected testNG will display the test case as failure/fail? if the result is expected test case result is passed?
very new to TestNG. my problem here is no matter how many times I run, the testNG result is PASSED.

```
public class TestNgbasic{  DesktopOptions option=new DesktopOptions();  

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
//  DesktopOptions option=new DesktopOptions();  // Start your outlook session
    option.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");      
}

@Test
public void testcase1 () throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
{
    WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Seven")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("plusButton")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("Eight")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("equalButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String result = driver.findElement(By.id("CalculatorResults")).getAttribute("Name");        
    if ("Display is 15".equals(result))
    {
        System.out.print("Pass");   
    }
    else 
        System.out.print("Fail");   
}
```

}

Comment: you have to use testNG assertions

Comment: any sample please ? :)

Comment: The link i added as example of both sofassert and hardassert , softassert just throws warning , normal `Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, expectedtitle);` fails the test . You have to import `import org.testng.Assert;`

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/7.1.1/org/testng/Assert.html

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/17295/40022

Answer (score 1):

**Please use TESTNG assert:**

Assert.assertEquals(actualtitle, expectedtitle); fails the test . You have to 
import import org.testng.Assert;

```
public class TestNgbasic{  DesktopOptions option=new DesktopOptions();  

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
//  DesktopOptions option=new DesktopOptions();  // Start your outlook session
    option.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");      
}

@Test
public void testcase1 () throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
{
    WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("Seven")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("plusButton")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("Eight")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("equalButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String result = driver.findElement(By.id("CalculatorResults")).getAttribute("Name");        
    Assert.assertEquals(result, "Display is 15");

}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! :)